# paste from clipboard transpose to last non empty cell

Tags: excel, transpose

i want a macro to paste values from clipboard ( values that i have copied from another source)
in transpose to last non empty cell in row E in worksheet "sheet1"

any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLastRowInCol(wks as excel.worksheet, col as long)
    dim rng as range
    with wks
        set rng = .cells(.rows.count, col).end(xlup)
        findLastRowInCol = rng.row
    end with
end function
```

To test from the Immediate pane:

```
debug.print findLastRowInCol(thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1"), 5)
```

This will give you the row of the last non-empty cell in the specified column. Note that this may not be the last used row of the worksheet; selecting a different column may give you a different result depending which is that column's last non-empty cell.

Edit: replaced activesheet with "sheet1"

Edit: sample code to use in another macro to paste in from some other source,

```
thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").cells(findLastRowInCol(thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1"), 5), 5).pastespecial paste:=xlAll
```

If pasting from another Excel sheet or to strip formatting, you can use e.g. "xlPasteSpecialValues"

Edited to add: to paste a row from another worksheet and transpose, use the above as far as ".pastespecial" then use some variation on:

```
.pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues, transpose:=True
```

The simplest implementation is,

```
sub PasteToE()
thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").cells(findLastRowInCol(thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1"), 5),5).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues, transpose:=True
end sub
```

Add a commandbutton to the other worksheet and assign this macro to it. Select your range and copy it, then click the button.

Comment: I will give a try but in your code i don't see anywhere about paste from clipboard and transpose

Comment: Added simple paste code on the bottom. You didn't specify what you are pasting or where from. This will affect how you transpose values.

Comment: i don't know how to edit your code in vba. i copy values from column in another sheet of the same workbook

Comment: Did you know you don't even need a macro just to copy and transpose? It's true! Select what you want to copy and then on the Home tab of the Ribbon, click "Copy". Then go to where you want to paste it and click in the last cell there. Go back to the Ribbon and click the little down arrow under "Paste". One option there will be "Transpose". Click that, and you're done.

Comment: So the question is, does my suggestion above meet your needs? Or do you still want a macro?

Comment: that you suggest is what i am doing now thats i want  a command button to make my life easier.

Comment: I have added a simple sample proc to the end of my answer above. I don't guarantee it will work first try as written: you may need to tweak it. For example you may need to change "sheet1" to match your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub WriteFromClipboard()
Dim refRow As Integer
Dim Data As DataObject
Dim DataText As String
On Error Resume Next
    'Get row to write data:
    refRow = 1 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        refRow = 1
    End If
    Err.Clear
    'Get data from clipboard:
    Set Data = New DataObject
    Data.GetFromClipboard
    DataText = Data.GetText
    'Write data from clipboard on the spreadsheet:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Clipboard doesn't contain valid data."
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(refRow, 5).Select
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i get an error               compile error:userdefined type not defined at third row

Comment: Sorry, you have to reference "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library". To do that go to Tools menu and then click on References... On the dialog box check the option "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" and then click OK. If for some reason that reference doesn't appear on the list, click on Browse and select the file FM20.DLL placed in the System32 subfolder of your Windows folder. Click OK and you're good to go :)

Comment: that's it...thank you for your support. i have made some changes because i want it to paste in transpose but to leave the formatting as it was. and rename sheet1 to desired name of the sheet. now it's just perfect